# php53 in CentOS 5.6: which package?

Tags: centos, php53

I see (using GNOME Package Manager) that there are two PHP 5.3 packages available for CentOS 5.6. One of them is "php53-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1", and the other is ""php53-5.3.3-1.el5". What's the difference between them? Some googling suggest that the former is the right one, but can anybody confirm? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Odd – what repository does the latter show as being in? I just checked various CentOS 5.6 servers of ours and we only have the "php53-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1" package.

If you are interested, we have used the Webtatic repository for more up to date PHP 5.3 packages (5.3.6). Details available here: http://www.webtatic.com/projects/yum-repository/

Comment: Honestly? I don't know. Using "yum list" I can see now only the "el5_6.1" ones, and with GNOME Package Manager, I still see several PHP-related packages (devel, bcmath, etc.), but when it comes to the main PHP one, I also see only "php53-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1". The only extra repository I have enabled is RPMForge.